# Find the multiplicites of the zeros of $\sin z - \tan z, z_0 =0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the multiplicites of the zeros of $\sin z - \tan z, z_0 =0$.

The mulitplicites of the zeros of $f(z)$ at $z_0$ is the positive integer $m$ for which there is a holomorphic function $g(z)$ such that $$f(z) = (z-z_0)^m g(z),\ g(z_0) \neq 0$$
Using the fact that $\sin z = \cos z \tan z$ and $\tan z$ is an odd function, I find the first few coefficents of $\tan z$. So now I have
\begin{align*}f(z) = \sin z - \tan z = z^3(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3!}) + z^5(\frac{2}{15}+\frac{1}{5!}) +... = z^2\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^{2n+1}\bigg)\end{align*}
for some coefficients $c_n$. I want to say multiplicites is $2$ but I don't think it is correct.

Comment: Why do you want to say that it is $2$? Because of the $z^2$ term out front? Why do you want to say that? Why do you think that isn't correct?

Comment: Yeah. And I am not sure if $g(z_0)$ is not zero here.

Comment: Also for every $z^{n=2k},\ k\in\mathbb{Z},\ c_n$ is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that the answer isn't $2$, and that this is the case because $g(0)=0$ (where $g$ is the infinite sum you have). To see this, take the middle expression in your chain equality and divide by $z^2$ - everything is still divisible by $z$. The correct expression is

$$z^3\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^{2n}\bigg)$$

This is because you didn't factor out as many $z$'s as you could. $c_0=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3!}=\frac{1}{6}$, so when we evaluate the power series at $0$ we get a nonzero term.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to figure the multiplicity of a zero is the following:

**Lemma** Let $f$ be a function which is analytic at $a$. Then $a$ is a zero of multiplicity $n$ if and only if 
$$f(a)=f'(a)=f''(a)=....=f^{(n-1)}(a)=0\\
f^{(n)}(a) \neq 0$$

**Proof:** Write the Taylor series at $a$, the claim is easy to show.

In this case
$$f(z)=\sin(z)-\tan(z) \\
f(0)=0\\
f'(0)=0 \\
f''(0)=0 \\
f'''(0) \neq 0$$

Therefore, it is a zero of multiplicity 3.

Answer (score 0):

I might have a solution. I'm not sure how to prove it rigorously.

Let $\sin{z}=\tan{z}=\frac{\sin{z}}{\cos{z}}$

Then, $$\sin{z}(\cos{z}-1)=0$$, or $$-2\sin{z}\sin^2{\frac{z}{2}}=0$$

So $0$ is a zero of $\sin{z}$ and a double root of $\sin^2{\frac{z}{2}}$ giving multiplicity 3.